# For loop which prints out every 3rd number

Tags: racket

I'm trying to make a for loop that iterates over a list of numbers and prints out every 3rd number.

Edit: I've only figured out how to use the for loop but I'm not entirely sure if there's a specific function I can use to only show every 3rd number. I feel like I might be on the right path when using car/cdr function except I'm getting an error

> rest: contract violation
>     expected: (and/c list? (not/c empty?))
>     given: 0

My code:

```
(for/list ([x (in-range 20)] #:when (car(cdr(cdr x)))) (displayln x))
```

Comment: The question asks about printing every _third_ number (e.g. 3, 6, 9, 12,....), but the example code provides every _second_ number. What is desired?

Comment: The goal is still to print out every 3rd number from the list. I've made changed to the post which will hopefully clear up any confusion I previously might've given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I'm trying to make a `for` loop that iterates over a list of numbers and prints out every 3rd number.*

Typically it is more useful to create a new list with the desired values, and then print those values, or pass them to a function, or do whatever else may be needed. `for/list` does indeed return a list, and this is one reason for problems encountered by OP example code. (Other problems in OP code include that `x` is a number with `[x (in-range 20)]`, so `(cdr x)` is not defined).

A possible solution would be to recurse over the input list, using `take` to grab the next three values, keeping the third, and using `drop` to reduce the input list:

```
;; Recurse using `take` and `drop`:
(define (every-3rd-1 lst)
  (if (< (length lst) 3)
      '()
      (cons (third (take lst 3))
            (every-3rd-1 (drop lst 3)))))
```

Another option would be to recurse on the input list using an auxiliary counter; starting from 1, only keep the values from the input list when the counter is a multiple of 3:

```
;; Recurse using an auxilliary counter:
(define (every-3rd-2 lst)
  (define (every-3rd-helper lst counter)
    (cond [(null? lst)
           '()]
          [(zero? (remainder counter 3))
           (cons (first lst) (every-3rd-helper (rest lst) (add1 counter)))]
          [else (every-3rd-helper (rest lst) (add1 counter))]))
  (every-3rd-helper lst 1))
```

Yet another possibility would be to use `for/list` to build a list; here `i` is bound to values from the input list, and `counter` is bound to values from a list of counting numbers:

```
;; Use `for/list` to build a list:
(define (every-3rd-3 lst)
  (for/list ([i lst]
             [counter (range 1 (add1 (length lst)))]
             #:when (zero? (remainder counter 3)))
    i))
```

This function (or any of them, for that matter) could be usefully generalized to keep every nth element:

```
;; Generalize to `every-nth`:
(define (every-nth n lst)
  (for/list ([i lst]
             [counter (range 1 (add1 (length lst)))]
             #:when (zero? (remainder counter n)))
    i))
```

Finally, `map` could be used to create a list containing every nth element by mapping over a range of every nth index into the list:

```
;; Use `map` and `range`:
(define (every-nth-map n lst)
  (map (lambda (x) (list-ref lst x)) (range (sub1 n) (length lst) n)))
```

If what OP really requires is simply to print every third value, rather than to create a list of every third value, perhaps the code above can provide useful materials allowing OP to come to a satisfactory conclusion. But, each of these functions can be used to print results as OP desires, as well:

```
scratch.rkt> (for ([x (every-3rd-1 '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p))])
               (displayln x))
c
f
i
l
o
scratch.rkt> (for ([x (every-3rd-2 '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p))])
               (displayln x))
c
f
i
l
o
scratch.rkt> (for ([x (every-3rd-3 '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p))])
               (displayln x))
c
f
i
l
o
scratch.rkt> (for ([x (every-nth 3 '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p))])
               (displayln x))
c
f
i
l
o
scratch.rkt> (for ([x (every-nth-map 3 '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p))])
               (displayln x))
c
f
i
l
o
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a template:

```
(for ([x (in-list xs)]
      [i (in-naturals]
   #:when some-condition-involving-i)
  (displayln x))
```